# Issue with org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils and Unix absolute/relative path

Tags: java, fileutils

I am facing issue with absolute/relative path and org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils on Unix box.

**Issue is:**-

I am using `cleanDirectory(..)` and `copyDirectory(..)` of `FileUtils`. It works fine if I use absolute path `/userName/data/feeds` but gives IllegalArgumentException when I use paths like `/data/feeds` and `data/feeds`.

Please suggest any probable solution. I don't want to use absolute path in my code!!!

Waiting for comments....

Answer (score 1):

**/data/feeds** is an absolute path too. If the file path starts with an `/` then it means that it starts from the root directory.
**data/feeds** probably does not work because you execute Java in a different directory than **/userName**, probably you start it from **/home/userName** ?

Comment: even if I use /data/feeds above mentioned code still gives IllegalArgumentException......cannot find path data/feeds